# Minimum number of complementary CMOS to implement \$F=ABC+\overline{(A+B+C)}\$?

Tags: digital-logic, logic-gates, cmos, homework, boolean-algebra

> Minimum number of complementary CMOS transistors pair will be required to implement function,\$F=ABC+\overline{(A+B+C)}\$ are?
>
> \$(A)6\$
>
> \$(B)7\$
>
> \$(C)8\$
>
> \$(D)9\$

---

I tried like this but I am getting 7 CMOS pair but answer key says its 9 CMOS pair.whats the mistake I am doing?
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You did it wrong by connecting the output of the first stage to the output of the second stage. The correct way would be :[image]

**TOTAL = 4 + 3 + 2 = 9 CMOS pairs**

Comment: sir i have still one doubt please clarify what will be the output when i cascade it like that in my answer?I am just confused why thats wrong actually.

Comment: Unpredictable/undefined if both outputs are driving different logic level at the same time.  We don't do it in a circuit.

Comment: You can do like that ONLY for open collector/drain gates, where only one of the gates drives the output at a time, and other gates goes to high impedance state. Check this Wikipedia article -   "Wired logic connection "

Comment: It's not just a logic problem. For anything other than ABC+(A+B+C)' one or two of the NMOS transistors in the first stage and one or two of the PMOS transistors in the second stage would be turned on. Briefly. Until something fails.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not in the second stage, it is in the 1st stage. A+B+C shouldn't be connected in series in nmos to get required answer, it is a blunder. But the not of A B C should be connected in series.So you require 3 not gates to prepare A B C not. So Then the 2nd stage is not even required. Thank you.